# PHP: Refresh everyone who's on a specific page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for a solution to refresh everyone who's currently on a specific site of my page. So for example user A takes an action and user B, C, D & E is on the same site where user A do's the action the same page should be reloaded for all users.

I'm currently using https://dashboard.pusher.com to send a PUSH via this gateway and then receive it on the frontend site where users are registered to a channel defined by an ID on the page. So when a push comes in though this channel the page refresh's:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var reloadPusher = new Pusher('XXX', {
        cluster: 'eu',
        forceTLS: true
    });

    var channel = reloadPusher .subscribe(jQuery('#page-id').text());
    channel.bind('reload', function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            location.reload();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

The point is that I don't want to use this external page so is there any possible way to do this directly and simple in PHP?

Comment: Pusher (or something like it) is definitely the best way to do this. There are PHP websocket libraries (for example: http://socketo.me/) but the work of implementing and keeping it running may justify keeping a managed service like Pusher.

Comment: @ceejayoz So you would say that this is the only and best solution?

Comment: No, it's hardly the only solution. As I said, you can certainly run your own Pusher-style system - they're just providing a ready-to-go websocket implementation. It's just going to be more work to DIY it; it's up to you whether Pusher's costs are high enough to justify the extra work.

Comment: This is quit a large topic (a little too broad) and not really suited for SO. You can look up publish-subscribe (pub/sub) model for a general architecture try a hand at a PHP implementation and if you run into specific issue ask those questions